# Website not loading device width tag

Tags: mobile, tags, viewport, meta

I have the meta tag in the head of the html

however, it shows my phone width at 980px. 
I've tried everything I can think of and I don't see anything in the js or any contradicting information.

link for the site:
www.velocitylv.com/calendar2.html

Answer (score 0):

The `<meta name="viewport">` tag isn't on your top document, it's inside one of the frames. The viewport meta tag will only take effect if it's on the top level document.

Answer (score 0):

Your tag is inside the frameset, not in your main `<head>` tag, see below:

[image]

You should place `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=0">` in the main `<head></head>` tags of your index.